# QGIS - How to create a matrix of maps based on attribute value

Tags: qgis, atlas

I’m trying to create a matrix of maps, or even lots of individual maps based on common attribute values but I’m struggling badly.  It can be done manually, and slowly, but I thought Atlas may be the able to automate the process, but it only seems to work at the row value level.

What I have is a large dataset (deliminated text layer) with the maximum count of each species at a given location on a given day.  Its arranged in long format so columns for this would be Date, Species, Location, Max Count.

What I want to create is 20 plots arranged as 4 columns (Species) and 5 rows (months).  The data points data for a given month/species would then populated each map.

Can it be done in an automated way in QGIS?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by *'only seems to work at the row level'*? Perhaps by including a screenshot of the result.

Comment: My apologies, row = feature.  I want to essentially group sets of features by attribute values and produce a map of each group.

Comment: Well, maybe you want to do groupby (ex. SQL) or draw various maps filtered by specific values. If you want to do this automatically with QGIS, you will have to use Model Builder, but you can filter the data by the values you want in the attribute table and set it in the direction of creating new data for drawings. Although SQL-based queries are possible in QGIS.. In terms of automation, it is the same as using Python. (You can also use Python in QGIS, but it will take time to learn.)

Comment: Is your Location column specific coordinates, or is the name of a study site, for example?